# Find the volume of triangular pyramid

Tags: vectors

I have a plane, $x+2y+3z=12$ with $x$-intercept of $12$, $y=6$, and $z=4$.
So between origin and these points, I have a pyramid.
$(0,0,0)$, $(12,0,0)$, $(0,6,0)$, $(0,0,4)$.

I need to work out the volume of this pyramid. I did it a few times and understand mostly how to do it, but I'm not getting the answer on the answer sheet, so maybe somebody could work it out and tell me what you get :)

Thanks a lot...

Comment: You could save yourself writing down the axis intercepts: they follow at once from the plane's formula...:)

Comment: Are you trying to calculate the volume using a formula, or by integration?

Comment: I thought if the lengths are 6,12,4 then i would just get the area of the cube, and then halve it?

Comment: If one knows the coordinates of all 4 for the vertices of the tetrahedron there is a "formula" involving determinants that allows one to find the volume of the tetrahedron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that pyramid's base (in fact, prism's area) is a right-angled triangle with known lengths of its legs, so its area $\;A\;$ is very easy to calculate, and since this is also a straight pyramid *also* its height $\;h\;$ is easy to calculate.

Now just use the volume formula

$$V=\frac13Ah$$

Comment: How do you know the height of the pyramid though?

Comment: Because its apex is at $\;(0,0,4)\;$ and it is on a perpendicular line to the base, namely: on the $\;z$-axis...!

Comment: I tried using the formula |x.(y x(cross product) z)| for parallelepiped and then halve it to find the area of the pyramid. Is that not right?

Comment: Do you want to *half* the corresponding paralleliped's volume? That'd be wrong, as you must divide it by 6, as user35's answer remarks. What's the problem with using the basic formula from analytic geometry?

Answer (score 0):

The volume of a pyramid is the $\frac{1}{6}$th of the volume of respective parallelepiped. So, we have $$V=\frac{1}{6} \cdot 12 \cdot 6 \cdot 4=48.$$

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know, or can't use, the formula for volume of a pyramid, this is not too hard to do as an integral.  In general, the volume of a solid $E$ is given by the integral $\iiint\limits_E dV$.

To do this you first need to figure out what the base triangle as.  As you noted, the vertices in the $xy$-plane have coordinates $(12, 0)$ and $(0, 6)$.  (I'm assuming this pyramid lives in the first octant / is bounded by the $xy$-plane below.)  The equation of the line from $(12, 0)$ to $(0, 6)$ is $y = 6 - \frac{x}{2}$.  So the base of the pyramid is the set

$$
\left\{ (x, y) \, \big| \, 0 \leq x \leq 12, \, 0 \leq y \leq 6 - \frac{x}{2} \right\}
$$

Solving for $z$ in your equation of the plane tells you the $z$-values are between $z = 0$ and $z = \frac{1}{3}(12 - x- 2y)$.

Putting all of this together, the pyramid is the following.

$
\text{Volume}(E) = \iiint\limits_E dV \\
= \int_0^{12} \int_0^{6 - x/2} \int_0^{(12 - x - 2y)/3} \, dz \, dy \, dx \\
= ...  \quad \text{(I cheated and did this in WolframAlpha)} \\
= 48
$

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was really interesting as well, but I haven't reached such a level yet. Hopefully I will eventually. And I'm in the last year of school. We do calculate volumes of donut like shapes with integrals like V = S( (f(x))2 - (g(x))2 ) dx. But that is still just one variable :P